# SAPUI5 UploadCollection - How to trigger Delete File?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I see uploaded files in my UploadCollection-Control when I Start the app.

I want to delete files, after pressing the 'X' button next to the file.

But after pressing the button, it doesn't call the DELETE_STREAM method in the backend.

Do I have to trigger DELETE_STREAM myself in the frontend?

And can I send parameters like documentid or custom parameters to DELETE_STREAM when I call it?

```
<UploadCollection 
                          id="UploadCollection"
                          mode="SingleSelectMaster" 
                          beforeUploadStarts="onBeforeUploadStarts" 
                          multiple="false"
                          instantUpload="false"
                          uploadUrl="/sap/opu/odata/sap/xyz" 
                          uploadComplete="onUploadComplete">
                          <items>
                            <UploadCollectionItem 
                              documentId="{Documentid}" 
                              fileName="{Filename}"                           url="/sap/opu/odata/sap/xyz/$value"
                              mimeType="{Mimetype}">
                            </UploadCollectionItem>
                          </items>
                        </UploadCollection>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the event [fileDeleted](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.UploadCollection#events/fileDeleted) of your UploadCollection.

```xml
<UploadCollection
    ...
    fileDeleted="onFileDeleted">
```

In this method you can get the binding context of the deleted item. Then with this information you do not trigger `DELETE_STREAM` but the `DELETE` method of your entity:

```js
onFileDeleted: function(oEvent) {
    const sPath = oEvent.getParameter("item").getBindingContext().getPath();
    this.getModel().remove(sPath, {
        success: (oData) => {},
        error: (oError) => {}
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, fileDeleted is not fired, looks like it's a known issue of UploadCollection? Is there another solution? Thanks

Comment: Personally I switched to the newer `sap.m.upload.UploadSet`